# printing dz when using “Indexing with boolean Arrays”

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Hello consider following code:

```
Z = cache
dZ = np.array(dA, copy=True) # just converting dz to a correct object. 
dZ[Z <= 0] = 0
```

I succeed for debugging reasons to print z and dz with following code

```
print("z = " + str(cache))
print("dz np array = " + str(np.array(dA, copy=True)))
```

But now my question. I like also to print the content of dz after the expression dZ[Z <= 0] = 0 but I do not succeed without any errors. What is the code I have to write to print the content of dZ after the indexing with boolean arrays

tnx,

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at what kinds of errors you get?  Normally `print(dZ)` is enough.

Comment: If I use the print(dz) command then I have dz is undefined. So I have to do it as explained in my first message. But as said and the very important is I want to print the content of dz after the expression dZ[Z <= 0] = 0 But I don't know how?

Comment: `dz` or `dZ`? there's a difference

Comment: dZ if I use print(dZ) then I have dZ is undefined. If I do it as eg: print("dZ=" + str(dZ[Z <= 0] = 0)) then I have you can not use an expression. If I do it like eg: print("dZ=" + str(dZ[ Z<= 0])) I have also error but don't know which one anymore. Anyway, I like to print Z, dZ and dZ after the expression. The first two I succeed as see above in my first question, I do not succeed for the third one...

Comment: Ok problem solved. dZ is accepted in my print command. Tnx for your time!